# Trying to fix these dmesg errors Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, grub2, dpkg, dmesg

Since updating to Debian Stretch I'm seeing these kernel messages while system boots up (in prior version's they did not show up at all):

```
dmesg -k -l err,warn



[    0.008642] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.008643] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
[    0.158780]  #2
[    0.238805]  #3
[    1.892878] r8169 0000:07:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   13.343259] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343270] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343275] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343279] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343282] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343286] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343289] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[   13.343293] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   13.991161] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   14.197061] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   14.197920] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
[   14.197936] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL] (Node f74a2168), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
[   14.500320] ATPX version 1, functions 0x00000033
[   16.393307] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
[   16.495635] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 5 was not initialized!
[   16.495639] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 8 was not initialized!
[   16.495642] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 2 was not initialized!
[   16.495644] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 3 was not initialized!
[   16.495647] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   86.108940] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
[ 2159.734851] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2160.173106] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
[ 2161.943232]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 2161.959231]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 2161.974867]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 2162.137235] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
[ 2163.144824] usb 1-1.1:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[ 2163.144829] usb 1-1.1:1.1: rebind failed: -517
```

Seems like some firmware issues are there which I am unable to fix despite trying `dpkg` and `dpkg-reconfigure` solutions I found online.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Broken ACPI firmware is the norm, not the exception.  You might be able to fix it eventually with a BIOS upgrade, but new BIOS versions may add new problems.  If your machine works as it is it might be safer to just let it be.  Either way it's a hardware problem not a Linux one.

Comment: would that mean I m having hardware issues related to radeon,iwlwifi & possible other components?

Comment: You can in fact run into all sorts of issues because of ACPI, but you probably won't.  As I said: if it works as it is just let it be.

Comment: I wont upgrade I just want to know about the situation

Comment: These messages were not appearing untill the system was upgraded to Debian Stretch,this means hardware problem likely occurred during or after the upgrade.

Comment: This just means the problem (whatever that might be) went undetected until you upgraded.  Most ACPI firmwares have bugs.  The vast majority of these bugs go undetected.  A minority of them are fixed from time to time, when you flush a new version of BIOS.  Sometimes new versions of the kernel get smarter and detect (and complain about) some of these bugs.  Ask on the kernel list what that error means if you're really concerned about it.

Comment: Regarding the "ACPI Error: " lines, in previous kernel versions these might have been *accidentally* omitted from 1) `dmesg -k -l err,warn` and 2) the messages shown during boot, because they were incorrectly logged as default messages, not "error" messages. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524202/acpi-error-message-ae-not-found-why-is-this-happening-now-it-did-not-happen-pr