# ACPI error message AE_NOT_FOUND. Why is this happening now? It did not happen previously

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, acpi

I have used Linux on my PC for a long time.  Some time recently, there is a new kernel error message on the text console.

It also appears as a message in red in `journalctl -p err`.  It did not appear like this before.

**Question:** Why did this change?

**Notice:** I am writing this very general question, in order to host the answer below.

**Notice:** ACPI error messages on specific systems might have more specific causes, problems, and solutions. For example, see these two questions:

1. [ACPI BIOS Error / AE_NOT_FOUND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/acpi-bios-error-ae-not-found)
2. [ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND infinitely on startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348806/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-infinitely-on-startup)

My error messages are:

```
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5caaa0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5caaa0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5ca758), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5ca9b0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5ca758), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psargs-359)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF] (Node ffff8d859a5ca9b0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparse-543)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [I just want to say it happens only on kernels 4.9.x [and above] on whatever distro.](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193531#c8)

> O.K. so the kernel bisection says the guilty commit is:
>
> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b5c0875a16039d90f4cdf6b75ae4031daae01d56
>
> > commit b5c0875a16039d90f4cdf6b75ae4031daae01d56
> >     Author: Lv Zheng <lv.zheng@intel.com>
> >     Date:   Thu Aug 4 16:42:49 2016 +0800
> >
> > ACPICA: Utilities: Introduce facility to allow Linux to set correct
> >     logging levels
>
> So it seems, at least for me, that this issue was always there, but
>   just not reported before. If I correctly understand bug 43229, the
>   root issue is actually a BIOS problem.
>
> I further tested on kernel 4.10-rc8, by reverting the above commit:
>
> ```
> doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ git log --oneline
> 1dc8c4f Revert "ACPICA: Utilities: Introduce facility to allow Linux to set correct logging levels"
> 7089db8 Linux 4.10-rc8
> ...
> ```
>
> And indeed upon resume from suspend, those messages no longer
>   appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can silence your error by disabling the libata ACPI probing with the kernel parameter `libata.noacpi=1`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.noacpi=1"
```